# How does geo-redundant storage help in recovering of VM in Azure

Tags: azure

when we create a VM in Azure we mention the storage account where the vhd will be. The storage account is set to Geo-Redundant.

If the region fails how would i be able to access the vhd which is suppose to have been backed up in another region?

Answer (score 1):

If a region fail-over occurs your storage account will be made available in the second region, this will then allow you to access the VHD files in that second region, you would then need to create new VM's in the second region, using the existing VHD files to rebuild the VM's.

Storage replication, as the name implies, only relates to storage. If you are concerned about HA for VM's in a region failure you need to look at replicating your VM's as whole in a second region, or using something like Azure VM backup or Azure Site Recovery.